# C# error basic function

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my function

```
public class PS3
{
    public static void restoreAllClassesNames(string A, string B, string C/*, string A1, string B1, string C1, string A2, string B2, string C2, string A3, string B3, string C3, string A4, string B4, string C4*/)
    {
        A = returnLine("a.txt", 0);
        B = returnLine("a.txt", 1);
        C = returnLine("a.txt", 2);
    }

    public static string returnLine(string fileName, int line)
    {
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(fileName);
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        string linePath;
        while ((linePath = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
            myList.Add(linePath);

        return myList[line];
    }
```

So, when I am do this :

```
Functions.PS3.restoreAllClassesNames(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
```

My textbox1 , 2 & 3 contains nothing, yet it should work

Comment: You might want to read [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) about parameter passing.

Answer (score 6):

You are passing in the value of the `Text` property of each `TextBox`, so changing that value within the `restoreAllClassesNames` method does nothing to the original control.

You can either pass in the controls themselves (since they are reference types):

```
public static void restoreAllClassesNames(Control A, Control B, Control C)
{
    A.Text = returnLine("a.txt", 0);
    B.Text = returnLine("a.txt", 1);
    C.Text = returnLine("a.txt", 2);
}
```

or make the strings `out` parameters:

```
public static void restoreAllClassesNames(out string A, out string B, out string C)
{
    A = returnLine("a.txt", 0);
    B = returnLine("a.txt", 1);
    C = returnLine("a.txt", 2);
}
```

and assign the text to the control from the calling method:

```
string a;
string b;
string c;

Functions.PS3.restoreAllClassesNames(out a, out b, out c);   

textBox1.Text = a;
textBox2.Text = b;
textBox3.Text = c;
```

you could also return a `List<string>`, a `Tuple<string, string, string>`, etc., etc.

Comment: Also, the code is leaking file handles because `SR` owns its underlying stream but isn't being closed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

StreamReader is looking for the file in bin\Debug\ folder

You can provide the filepath

```
public static string returnLine(string fileName, int line)
        {
            var filepath = "D:/" + fileName; /*Your file path*/
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(filepath);
                List<string> myList = new List<string>();
                string linePath;
                while ((linePath = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
                    myList.Add(linePath);
                if (myList.Count > 0)
                    return myList[line];
                else
                    return "No record found";
            }
            else
            {
                return "File not found";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

pass the reference of the string not its values :

```
  public static void restoreAllClassesNames( ref string A,  ref string B,  ref string C/*, string A1, string B1, string C1, string A2, string B2, string C2, string A3, string B3, string C3, string A4, string B4, string C4*/)
            {
                A = returnLine("a.txt", 0);
                B = returnLine("a.txt", 1);
                C = returnLine("a.txt", 2);
            }
```

You call your method like this

```
string txt1 = textBox1.Text;
string txt2 = textBox2.Text;
string txt3 = textBox3.Text;
    Functions.PS3.restoreAllClassesNames(ref txt1 , ref txt2 , ref txt3 );
textBox1.Text = txt1;
textBox2.Text = txt2;
textBox3.Text = txt3;
```

Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: You can't pass a property by reference.

Comment: No need to initialize txt1, txt2 and txt2; just make the parameters `out` instead of `ref`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque : You can use ref or out in this case ( twice can solve the problem) , there is no difference( for me) except the initialization

Comment: @LamloumiAfif, yes, but using `ref` is misleading for the caller, since it implies that the method will use the initial value of the parameter.